# AngularJS use angular module in custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-module

I have a custom service for generating token, in this service I need to use an MD5 function, the MD5 function is in the module `angular-md5`

here is my service code, the `generate_token` function use `md5.createhash()` from the angular module but I'm getting ths error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined`

I think I have made something wrong but I can't see what

```
angular.module('app.services', ['angular-md5'])

.service('Auth', [function($scope, md5){
    var self = this;

    this.rand_alphanumeric = function() {
        var subsets = [];
        subsets[0] = [48, 57]; // ascii digits
        subsets[1] = [65, 90]; // ascii uppercase English letters
        subsets[2] = [97, 122]; // ascii lowercase English letters 

        // random choice between lowercase, uppercase, and digits
        s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0
        ascii_code = Math.floor(Math.random() * (subsets[s][1] - subsets[s][0] + 1) + subsets[s][0]);
        return String.fromCharCode(ascii_code);
    }

    this.generateToken = function() {
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
            str += self.rand_alphanumeric();
        return md5.createHash(str);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the dependency array injection properly

Try this

```
angular.module('app.services', ['angular-md5'])

.service('Auth', ['$scope','md5',function($scope, md5){
var self = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the brackets before `function($scope, md5)` and you should be fine. In angular you have different possibilites for the injection syntax. see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define $scope and md5 in the array before function.

e.g.

```
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'md5', function($scope, md5) {
      $scope.$watch('email' ,function() {
        $scope.message = 'Your email Hash is: ' + md5.createHash($scope.email || '');
      });
    }]);
```